# Convolution: Integral vs. Discrete sum

Tags: integration, convolution, riemann-integration

I recently stumbled across a question which really confused my understanding of convolution. It's the relation between the continuous integral and the discrete counterpart I don't get.

What I learned in school was:

$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx = \lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \sum_{i=1}^{n} f(x_i) \cdot \Delta x_i$

Why is the discrete version of a convolution integral for two series $f$ and $g$ defined as $(f * g)(n) = \sum_{k} f(k) \cdot g(n-k)$ and not some kind of "area under the curve"  $\sum_{k} f(k) \cdot g(n-k) \cdot \Delta x_k$?

So why can't I say for a given $t$:  $\int_{0}^{t} h(\tau) d\tau = \lim_{\Delta \tau\to 0} \sum_{i=1}^{n} h(\tau_i) \cdot \Delta \tau_i$ with $h(\tau_i) = f(\tau_i) \cdot g(t - \tau_i)$?

Comment: Simply because they took $\Delta x_i=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, the [Convolution Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Definition) between two functions $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ is defined as

$$(f*g)(t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\tau)g(t-\tau)\,d\tau$$

If both $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ are causal functions (i.e., $f(t)$ is causal if $f(t)=0$ for $t<0$), then

$$\begin{align}
(f*g)(t)&=\int_{0}^t f(\tau)g(t-\tau)\,d\tau\\\\
&=\lim_{\max_{i\in[1,n]}(\Delta \tau_i)\to 0}\sum_{i=1}^n f(\tau_i)g(t-\tau_i)\Delta \tau_i\tag1
\end{align}$$

---

For the discrete case, we sample $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ at integer values of $t$.  So, in $(1)$, we set $t=n$.

Moreover, we define $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ in terms of a train of Dirac Deltas $\delta(t-k)$ with weights $f(k)$ and $g(k)$ so that $f(t)=\sum_{m=1}^n f(m)\delta(t-m)$, and $g(t)=\sum_{\ell=1}^n g(\ell)\delta(t-\ell)$ in the integral in $(1)$.  Proceeding, we find that

$$\begin{align}
(f*g)(n)&=\int_{0}^t f(\tau)g(t-\tau)\,d\tau\\\\
&=\int_{0}^n \sum_{m=1}^n f(m)\delta(\tau-m)\sum_{\ell=1}^n g(\ell)\delta(n-\tau-\ell)\,d\tau\\\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^n f(m)\sum_{\ell=1}^n g(\ell)\underbrace{\int_0^n \delta(\tau-m)\delta(n-\tau-\ell)\,d\tau}_{=1\,\,\text{for}\,\,\ell=n-m\,\,\text{and otherwise}\,\,=0}\\\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^n f(m)g(n-m)
\end{align}$$

Comment: I think I understand the derivation, but I'm confused about how this works in terms of the units. The continuous integral seems to have different units than the discrete case. Likewise, the discrete case is not normalized to the sampling rate?